Cell execution time with ipython-autotime
I am using ipython-autotime with jupyterlab notebook, I am not able to see cell execution time when there is an error in code of cell to be run.
I tried printing pre_run_cell and post_run_cell events and post_run_cell isn't even called when there's an error.
used below script to print the events=>
from datetime import datetime
from IPython import get_ipython

# Custom hook for pre_run_cell
def pre_run_hook(*args, **kwargs):
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] pre_run_cell called")

# Custom hook for post_run_cell
def post_run_hook(*args, **kwargs):
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] post_run_cell called")

# Get the current IPython shell (kernel)
ipython = get_ipython()

# Register the hooks
ipython.events.register('pre_run_cell', pre_run_hook)
ipython.events.register('post_run_cell', post_run_hook)


